# ColdFusion date subtraction

Tags: coldfusion

I am converting a ColdFusion application to .NET, and I have a question about date subtraction.

In the following if statement, qTripID.etd is the utc date and time of a flight departure, the comment says that that it is testing whether the flight has already departed.

```
<cfif qTripID.etd - DateConvert("local2utc",Now()) LT 0.166666666666667>
```

What type of information does the expression above return?

minutes? days? hours?

Comment: you can use `<cfdump var="#qTripID.etd - DateConvert("local2utc",Now()) LT 0.166666666666667#">` to find out what it returns.

Comment: hi Matt, thanks for the suggestion, but I cant because I dont have access to the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The entire expression:

`qTripID.etd - DateConvert("local2utc",Now()) LT 0.166666666666667`

returns a boolean value: 'LT' is ColdFusion's 'less than' operator.

I think you're asking what units is the `0.166666666667`? In which case it is days - the 0.1666... value being 4 hours.